# How to group core data objects so that all or none are deleted by the system?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**What strategy can I use to solve this scenario?**

I have a view controller that displays all events occurring on a particular day.

Events get populated in `viewWillAppear` by first trying to fetch objects. If no objects are found then it requests events for that day with a web service.

If the user wants to go to the next day then they can hit the "next day" button. Like `viewWillAppear`, this button tries to fetch and if no results are returned it reaches out to the web service.

**Problem:** If the user hits "next day" too many times and then returns to the first day, the fetch will not return any objects OR worse, it will only return some objects for that day.

This gives the impression to the user that they are viewing a complete list of events for the day when in fact it is only partial.

My theory is that there is some sort of limit to the allowable memory space of core data objects you can create and so it deallocates older ones. Is this possible?

How can I write my events view controller so that iOS either deletes ALL objects for a particular day or keeps all for that day and deletes another day instead?

Comment: It sounds more like you have some logic error in your code.  You might want to post the code you are using to fetch and display your data.  If you are using a NSFetchedResultsController and UITableView with the correct delegate methods you should always see the correct data. Clicking "Next Day" should simply apply a filter to your fetchedResultsController query to return the subset of data for that day, or if there is none to invoke a background task to load the data.

Comment: Your theory is not correct. Core Data never deallocates objects. The worst that will happen is that these objects are turned into faults. And if you access them the next time from your code, they will be turned back into non-fault objects. That happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

@DuncanGroenwald and @MatthiasBauch are both correct in this case.

The app logic was wrong because web service fetched events were repeating EventIDs and therefore had the same IDs on a particular day of the week.

For example, maybe EventIDs 1-4 were on any Monday fetched, 5-7 on Tuesday, 8-10 Wednesday..., etc. When any two of the same day of week were created, let's say August 15th (Saturday) and August 22nd (Saturday), the first day's (August 15th) activities would be removed because the EventIDs were the same.

So really I was unaware of this fact and my original assumption that I was running out of memory was incorrect. I was obviously hitting "Next Day" so many times that I got to the same say of the week eventually.

My solution was to make the eventID unique by adding the date:

originalEventID**Date** = originalEventID (12345) + **Date**(08152015)

so eventDateID == 1234508152015

I also had to create different accessors methods for talking to web services with particular originalEventIDs vs internal eventDateIDs.

Now the app keeps all the events and I can stop blaming iOS!